# How to use a recursive function to count the sum of the positive elements of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

How to use a recursive function to count the sum of the positive elements of a list?

I'm not sure how to go about it? I know how to do it without using a recursive function:

```
sum=0
for i in range(len(List)):
    if List[i]>0:
        sum=sum+List[i]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using recursion to calculate sum of only positive elements in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910878/using-recursion-to-calculate-sum-of-only-positive-elements-in-array)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question)[https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

You need to *divide the problem*, into a 'current' step and the remainder to be handled by recursion. You also need to determine when to end the recursion.

- The current step is determining what to sum in this step. That's the current value, or `0` if the value is smaller than 0.
- The remainder is summing the current value to the recursive call for the rest of the list.
- You end the recursion when an empty list is passed in; the sum of an empty list is always 0.

In the end, that gives:

```
def recursive_positive_sum(l):
    # end recursion for an empty list
    if not l:
        return 0
    # get a value
    value = l[0]
    if value < 0:
        value = 0
    # recurse, sum the value with the remainder
    return value + recursive_positive_sum(l[1:])
```

We can use a `max()` to get the value or `0` and inline that:

```
def recursive_positive_sum(l):
    if not l:
        return 0
    return max(l[0], 0) + recursive_positive_sum(l[1:])
```

Demo:

```
>>> def recursive_positive_sum(l):
...     if not l:
...         return 0
...     return max(l[0], 0) + recursive_positive_sum(l[1:])
...
>>> recursive_positive_sum([])
0
>>> recursive_positive_sum([-42])
0
>>> recursive_positive_sum([-42, 10, -81, 100])
110
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be one wy of doing it.

```
def fun(l):
    if len(l)==0:
        return 0
    num = l.pop()
    if num > 0:
        return num + fun(l)
    return fun(l)
```

but be careful. this function destroys the list that has benn passed to it. so make a copy of your list before passing it to the function or:

```
def fun(l):
    if len(l)==0:
        return 0
    if len(l)==1:
        return l[0]
    num = l[0]
    if num > 0:
        return num + fun(l[1:])
    return fun(l[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the sum_positive_numbers function, as a recursive function that returns the sum of all positive numbers between the number n received and 1. [solved]

```
def sum_positive_numbers(n):
  if n <= 1:
       return n
  return n + sum_positive_numbers(n-1)
```

---

```
print(sum_positive_numbers(3)) # Should be 6
print(sum_positive_numbers(5)) # Should be 15
```

Answer (score 0):

As a new learner without recursion i would write a few more lines of code as follows. This is for the problem of adding the numbers till n.

```
def sum_positive_numbers(n):
    # Initialise variables
    sum=0
    i=1
    while i<n+1:
        sum=sum+i
        i+=1
    return sum
```

Comment: `n` is a list so your while loop is wrong it should be `i<len(n)+1`.